# How to concatenate and sum multiple line in a file using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file `A.csv` (field separator = `,`):

```
Lane,SampleID,Index,# Reads,# Perfect Index Reads,# One Mismatch Index Reads,# of >= Q30 Bases (PF),Mean Quality Score (PF)
1,4331099,AACCATAGAA-CCATCTCGCC,301713,291343,10370,10159753,33.99
1,4360506,GCCGCACTCT-CGAGGTCGGA,271546,261268,10278,9107606,33.91
2,4331099,AACCATAGAA-CCATCTCGCC,297033,286679,10354,10036901,34.06
2,4360506,GCCGCACTCT-CGAGGTCGGA,266222,255838,10384,8954558,33.96
3,4331099,AACCATAGAA-CCATCTCGCC,293499,281393,12106,9838039,33.89
3,4360506,GCCGCACTCT-CGAGGTCGGA,262214,249940,12274,8741308,33.78
4,4331099,AACCATAGAA-CCATCTCGCC,289896,277519,12377,9735725,33.93
4,4360506,GCCGCACTCT-CGAGGTCGGA,255337,243245,12092,8530109,33.82
```

And I want to concatenate the line based on the `SampleID` , print the `Index` column and sum the others column (`# Reads,# Perfect Index Reads,# One Mismatch Index Reads,# of >= Q30 Bases (PF),Mean Quality Score (PF)`) and remove the column `Lane` . And put the result in another file Like this :

```
SampleID,Index,# Reads,# Perfect Index Reads,# One Mismatch Index Reads,# of >= Q30 Bases (PF),Mean Quality Score (PF)
4331099,AACCATAGAA-CCATCTCGCC,1182141,1136934,45207,39770418,135.87
4360506,GCCGCACTCT-CGAGGTCGGA,1055319,1010291,45028,35333581,135.47
```

Do you have some `awk` command (or else) in order to do that?

I've done some test like this but nothing close to a start:

```
awk '{
      if(NR!=2){a[$1]=$2";"a[$1]}
      else print $0}
    END{
      n = asorti(a, b);
      for (n in b) {
      print b[n],a[b[n]]
      }
    }'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gawk -F, -v s=4 '
    NR>1{ for(c=s; c<=NF; c++) sum_[c][$2 FS $3] +=$c; next }
        { sub(/^[^,]*,/ ,""); print }
END{ for(r in sum_[s]){
         printf ("%s", r);
         for(i=s; i<=NF; i++) printf (",%s", sum_[i][r]);
         print ""
     };
}' infile
```

---

Keep the order as original file:

```
gawk -F, -v s=5 '
    NR>1{ 
          if(!seen[$3 FS $4]) seen[$3 FS $4]=$1;
          for(c=s; c<=NF; c++) sum_[c][$3 FS $4] +=$c; next 
        }
        { sub(/^([^,]*,){2}/ ,""); print "1 "$0 }
END{ for(r in sum_[s]){
         printf ("%s %s", seen[r], r);
         for(i=s; i<=NF; i++) printf (",%s", sum_[i][r]);
         print ""
     };
}' <(nl -s ',' -w 1 infile) |sort |cut -d' ' -f2-
```

---

or with GNU `datamash` which you may prefer it:

```
datamash -H  -t,  -s  -g2,3  sum 4-8 <infile
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! it works well. Do you know a solution for printing the line in the same order that the original file ?

Comment: Unfortunately the edit don't print in the order and don't print the header

Comment: are you working on Windows env? do `dos2unix filename` to convert the Windows line ending to Unix type, based on your given data, command works perfectly with no issues.

Comment: I've try to dos2unix first and then run your script and the header is here but mixed with all the other line that are not in order

Comment: @nstatam so the simplification data you showed in the question might be differ from your real data format.

Comment: not really. I `cat -A` on the file and nothing wrong with it. The structure of the file is the same as the simplification data.

Comment: @nstatam please post the output you are seeing when running the second `awk` command into your question, I will see what is the issue.